# .MapNetworkDrive with password from Get-Credential

Tags: powershell

I am working on installing software across multiple servers with various versions of Powershell.
Originally I was using New-PSDrive cmdlets to mount a drive and copy/install files from. Some servers now complain that New-PSDrive does not accept -Credential argument despite having PS4.0.

I am now trying to use .MapNetworkDrive for legacy purposes but cannot seem to be able to pass Password to it via a variable:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
$net = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network    
$net.MapNetworkDrive("u:", "\\myshare", $false, "$creds.UserName","$creds.Password")
```

I get an error: *Exception calling "MapNetworkDrive" with "5" argument(s): "The specified network password is not correct.*

Any suggestions?
Many thanks,

Comment: the password is almost certainly still a SecureString ... and the `WScript` stuff does not know anything about that. i suspect you will need to extract the actual password as plain text to use it.

Comment: Thanks, Lee. I tried using a variable with plain text password and it does not like it either. Is there a method to properly expand variable inside the quotes?

Comment: you are welcome! i didn't notice the use of compound objects in the quotes. [*blush*] you can get that by forcing them to be evaluated _before_ the string is expanded. thus >>> `$("$creds.UserName)"` <<< note the variable-dot-property is wrapped in `$()`. also, you can get the plain password from the $Creds variable thus >>> `$Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password` <<<

Comment: Man, you are the awesomeness. That worked perfectly! Much appreciated. This IS the answer

Comment: taking your hint, i went ahead and posted it as an Answer. glad to know that you got it working as needed. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two problems going on here. [*grin*]

- `WScript` COM objects do not understand `SecureString` objects
  your `$Creds.Password` is stored as a `System.Security.SecureString` and that is not something that the `WScript` stuff knows about.
  you can see that with `$Creds.Password`.
  you would need to use something like >>> `$Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password`.
- compound objects - like `"$creds.UserName"` - don't expand as expected when inside double quotes
  you will get `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential.UserName` from that.
  you need to force the variable-dot-property to evaluate *before* the string is expanded. thus >>> `"$($Creds.UserName)"`.

so your line of code ...

```
$net.MapNetworkDrive("u:", "\\myshare", $false, "$creds.UserName","$creds.Password")
```

... would become something like this ...

```
$net.MapNetworkDrive(
    "u:",
    "\\myshare",
    $false,
    "$($creds.UserName)",
    "$($Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)"
    )
```

however, i suspect you could leave off the quotes for the last two lines ... and then would not need the `$()` wrapper. [*grin*]

Comment: That's it! Many thanks! got it working properly now

Comment: @Norskyi - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]